# Copy rows with a specific value to another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a huge Excel worksheet which contains 200,000 rows. The data is about 120 subjects which are listed in column B, like `sinani-01` to `sinani-120`. I need to copy all rows where column B contains `sinani-01`, for example, and paste them to new sheet. Or at least just select them?
Can you please let me know how to do this in VBA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel has an `AutoFilter` function that you can use to select only the rows that contain a specific value. You use it like this:

```
' Filter column B by a specific value...
Range("B:B").AutoFilter 1, "sinani-01"

' Copy all visible rows to a new sheet...
Range("B:B").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy Sheets("sinani-01").Range("A1")

' Turn the AutoFilter back off...
Range("B1").AutoFilter
```

Comment: Thanks Bond but I am getting an error `Invalid Outside Procedure` Error

Comment: You need to add these lines to a macro or subroutine. Do you have one started already?

Comment: Sorry I got it now , the Filtering part working fine but the copy not working and I am getting error "424" `Object required ` at `Range("B:B").Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Sheet2.Range("A1")`

Comment: Do you have a `Sheet2`? Or are you using a different Sheet object there?

Comment: Oh I see! is there any way to automaticaly create it if not exist? even with the name of filter like  `"sinani-05"` which we used in `Range("B:B").AutoFilter 1, "sinani-05"`

Comment: You can add a sheet and give it a name like this: `Sheets.Add().Name = "sinani-05"`. But you'd need to change the code above to reference the sheet by _sheet name_ (`"sinani-05"`) and not by its _object name_ (`"Sheet2"`). I'll update the code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84265/discussion-between-suffii-and-bond).

Comment: Click on the chat link above and let's discuss it there.